# How to calculate the median value in Postgresql without using window function?

Tags: postgresql, join, group-by, count, median

I have a table like this:

[image]

Now I have this code that can get the median value:

```
SELECT ROUND((t.middle1 + b.middle2) / 2, 2) AS median_item_count  
FROM (  
  SELECT MAX(item_count) AS middle1
  FROM (
    SELECT item_count,
           COUNT(*) OVER() AS row_count,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY item_count) AS row_number
    FROM orders
    WHERE item_count <> 0
  ) top
  WHERE (row_number::float / row_count) <= 0.50
) t,
(
  SELECT MIN(item_count) AS middle2
  FROM (
    SELECT item_count,
           COUNT(*) OVER() AS row_count,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY item_count DESC) AS row_number
    FROM orders
    WHERE item_count <> 0
  ) bottom
  WHERE (row_number::float / row_count) <= 0.50
) b
;
```

How can I get the median value without using window function OVER()and without using the percentile_disc function???

Comment: Why would you want to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this function which calculates the median of numeric array elements:

```
create or replace function median(numeric[])
returns numeric language sql immutable as
$$
    select avg(val)
    from (
        select val
        from unnest($1) val
        order by 1
        limit 2 - mod(array_upper($1, 1), 2)
        offset ceil(array_upper($1, 1) / 2.0) - 1
    ) sub;
$$;

select median(array_agg(item_count))
from orders;
```

Comment: That. Is. Great.